# Visualizing JSON results from Microsoft Azure Read API

Tags: python, json, azure, ocr, azure-cognitive-services

I was wondering whether there's any Python-based tool/script that I can use to visualize the OCR results, in JSON format, that I got after using Microsoft Azure Read API on a PDF document.

I've found [this one](https://github.com/ikivanc/OCRVisualizer/) but it's only available for MS Windows users.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a brand new online portal provided by Microsoft to test this service, among others, without developing (but it will use your own Azure resources): https://preview.vision.azure.com/demo/OCR

The advantage is that it will directly list your available resources so you just have to pick the right one, then you test, and there are also some samples.

I tested, it works with a PDF:

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you very much, Nicolas!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [link](https://github.com/microsoft/Cognitive-Samples-IntelligentKiosk) to kiosk sample on github for computer vision explorer.

Document: https://github.com/microsoft/Cognitive-Samples-IntelligentKiosk/blob/master/Documentation/VisionAPIExplorer.md

Direct download: http://aka.ms/kioskapp

Comment: Thank you very much, Ram-msft!

Comment: I'm under the impression that the first link requires Windows 10 and the other ones do not take into account the pre-computer JSON files. Am I right?